# Query all Windows Services with JNA

Tags: java, api, winapi, windows-services, jna

Currently I'm trying to query all installed Windows Services from (remote) machine.
I had a look at `win32.Advapi32`.

> But here I can only "get" a defined (I have to give a "ServiceName") Windows Services. (Advapi32.INSTANCE.OpenSCManager, Advapi32.INSTANCE.OpenService, Advapi32.INSTANCE.QueryServiceStatusEx)

Do you know any API which allows to query all Windows Services from (remote) machine?

EDIT://

I tried it allready with the following code. But it aborts hardly with no error message!

```
public void getService(){
    IntByReference size = new IntByReference();
    IntByReference lppcbBytesneeded = new IntByReference();
    IntByReference retz = new IntByReference();
    SC_HANDLE scm = Advapi32.INSTANCE.OpenSCManager(null, null, Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE);
    boolean ret = CustomAdvapi32.INSTANCE.EnumServicesStatusEx(scm, 0, 0x00000030, 0x0000000, null, lppcbBytesneeded, 
            retz, size, null);
    //CustomAdvapi32.INSTANCE.EnumServicesStatusEx(hSCManager, InfoLevel, dwServiceType, dwServiceState, 
    //cbBufSize, pcbBytesNeeded, lpServicesReturned, lpResumeHandle, pstzGroupName)
     int error = Native.getLastError();

       Memory buf = new Memory(lppcbBytesneeded.getValue());
       size.setValue(retz.getValue());
       ret = CustomAdvapi32.INSTANCE.EnumServicesStatusEx(scm, 0, 0x00000030, 0x0000000,
               buf, lppcbBytesneeded, retz, size, null);
       error = Native.getLastError();


       ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS serviceInfo = new ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS(buf);
       Structure[] serviceInfos = serviceInfo.toArray(retz.getValue());

       for(int i = 0; i < retz.getValue(); i++) {
         serviceInfo = (ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS) serviceInfos[i];
         System.out.println(serviceInfo.lpDisplayName + " / " + serviceInfo.lpServiceName);
       }
}
```

Comment: Apparently [the `sc` command can do it](http://www.randomsupport.com/rs/blogs/index.php?title=howto_remotely_query_windows_service_inf&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1), and I would assume it's using SCManager functions to do so.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But 1. I can't/won't call a "3rd party" tool and read the stream. 2. hmm I don't found out anything about which apis this tool is calling. The question is: Which API this tool calls to query all installed windows services? But thanks so far

Comment: It looks like [`EnumServicesStatusEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682640(v=vs.85).aspx) is what you want.

Comment: tried it allready, but it aborts harldy. I edited the code above

Comment: Please mark in the code where you see the failure/crash.  Make sure you run with `-Djna.protected=true` (system property).

Answer (score 1):

You've incorrectly mapped `EnumServicesStatusEx`.  The sixth argument needs to be the size of the buffer passed in (in your first call, this should be zero).  The pointer to the required size would then come next.

Note that `EnumServicesStatusEx` requires 10 arguments and you've only mapped it with nine.