# Get list of services using JNA

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I need to list all of the services installed, running and stopped `(STATE = ALL)`. Earlier I was using command "sc query" but I need to do this using JNA. I've never used JNA before so I don't know much.

I found this [Query all Windows Services with JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562528/query-all-windows-services-with-jna) and did what was told in the answer but I can't get it to work.

```
public void getService(){
    IntByReference size = new IntByReference();
    IntByReference lppcbBytesneeded = new IntByReference();
    IntByReference retz = new IntByReference();
    lppcbBytesneeded.setValue(0);
    Winsvc.SC_HANDLE scm = Advapi32.INSTANCE.OpenSCManager(null, null, Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE);
    boolean ret = CustomAdvapi32.INSTANCE.EnumServicesStatusEx(scm.getPointer(), 0, 0x00000030, 0x0000003, null, 0, lppcbBytesneeded,
            retz, size, null);
    int error = Native.getLastError();

    Memory buf = new Memory(lppcbBytesneeded.getValue());
    size.setValue(retz.getValue());
    ret = CustomAdvapi32.INSTANCE.EnumServicesStatusEx(scm.getPointer(), 0, 0x00000030, 0x0000000,
            buf, lppcbBytesneeded.getValue(), lppcbBytesneeded, retz, size, null);
    error = Native.getLastError();


    ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS serviceInfo = new ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS(buf);
    Structure[] serviceInfos = serviceInfo.toArray(retz.getValue());

    for(int i = 0; i < retz.getValue(); i++) {
        serviceInfo = (ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS) serviceInfos[i];
        System.out.println(serviceInfo.lpDisplayName + " / " + serviceInfo.lpServiceName);
    }
}
```

All I can get from this is error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at com.sun.jna.Structure.toArray(Structure.java:1562)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.toArray(Structure.java:1587)
at Main.getService(Main.java:156)
at Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in `size.setValue(retz.getValue());`. When you call the method a second time, you are using `size` as the `lpResumeHandle` field:

> A pointer to a variable that, on input, specifies the starting point
>   of enumeration. You must set this value to zero the first time the
>   EnumServicesStatusEx function is called. On output, this value is zero
>   if the function succeeds. However, if the function returns zero and
>   the GetLastError function returns ERROR_MORE_DATA, this value
>   indicates the next service entry to be read when the
>   EnumServicesStatusEx function is called to retrieve the additional
>   data.

So in your second call you're telling JNA to start iterating after the last element in the previous list.   Not surprisingly, you're getting an empty array (`retz.getValue()` == 0) which `Structure.toArray()` can't handle.

You should be calling `EnumServicesStatusEx` with that parameter set to 0 to start enumeration at the beginning.